# Solid JS library that can use OAuth2 to gather information from external Accounts

Tags: oauth-2.0, integration, next-auth

I stumbled upon https://next-auth.js.org/ which is great for giving users the possibility to sign up for my website with github and slack for example.

Since I do not want multiple logins with the same email and different providers (security issue -> see here https://next-auth.js.org/faq), my question is. Could there be a way to still use next auth, but only for linking, but not for login? Or can anyone recommend a library that does the authentication but not the login?

Use case:

1. User registers with Github and is logged in
2. User clicks on connect with Slack (OAuth2 procedure etc.) but this time he is not able to login with that
3. I pull data from slack periodically and assign it to the user (comment done in a channel etc.)